# How do i resolved user's post name which display email instead of their full name in a social media app am creating?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Am currently working on a social media up in Django but am facing a challenge with the post model app since it displays their email address, when they post a pic or a write feed post instead of their full name! My user model authenticate with email address rather than users name. I don't know if  this is the actually course of the problem! How do i get users full name on their post instead? I still want to be able to authenticate users with email but their post should be displayed in their full name.

```
Here my user's model
```

```
class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email,username,last_name, password, **extra_fields):
        values = [email,username]
        field_value_map = dict(zip(self.model.REQUIRED_FIELDS, values))
        for field_name, value in field_value_map.items():
            if not value:
                raise ValueError('The {} value must be set'.format(field_name))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            email=email,
            username=username,
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, username, first_name,last_name, phone_number, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email,username, first_name,last_name, phone_number, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, username,phone_number, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email,username,phone_number, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    cover_image = models.ImageField(default="default", upload_to="cover_images",blank=True, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default="default.png",blank=True,null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=120)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    hide_email= models.BooleanField(default=True)
    SEX_CHOICES = (
        ('F', 'Female',),
        ('M', 'Male',),
        ('U', 'Unsure',),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=SEX_CHOICES,
    
    )


    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username','phone_number']
    
    def get_profile_image_filename(self):
        return str(self.profile_image)[str(self.profile_image).index('profile_images/' + str(self.pk) + "/"):]

    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username.split()[0]


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    FriendList.objects.get_or_create(user=insta
```

```
here is my Post model
```

```
class Post(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(max_length=5000, blank=True)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='path/to/img' ,blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    

    @property
    def pic_url(self):
        if self.pic and hasattr(self.pic, 'url'):
            return self.pic.url

    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('feed', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def get_date_posted(self):
        time = datetime.now()
        if self.date_posted.minute == time.minute:
            return str(time.minute - self.date_posted.minute) + " mins ago"
        else:
            if self.date_posted.day == time.day:
                return str(time.hour - self.date_posted.hour) + " hrs"
            else:
                if self.date_posted.month == time.month:
                    return str(time.day - self.date_posted.day) + "d"
                else:
                    if self.date_posted.year == time.year:
                        return str(time.month - self.date_posted.month) + " months ago"
        return self.date_posted
 

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='likes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='likes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    like_date  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def get_like_date(self):
        time = datetime.now()
        if self.like_date.day == time.day:
            return str(time.hour - self.like_date.hour) + " hrs ago"
        else:
            if self.date_posted.month == time.month:
                return str(time.day - self.like_date.day) + " days ago"
            else:
                if self.like_date.year == time.year:
                    return str(time.month - self.like_date.month) + " months ago"
        return self.like_date
```

[![This is the result is get instead of user's full name][2]][2]

Comment: To display the full name instead of email (actually the username) use `post.user_name.get_full_name()` of in template `{{ post.user_name.get_full_name }}` oh and btw your `get_like_date` is django's build-in filter just use `{{ like.like_date|timesince }}`

Comment: I will add it as an answet then so others can also benefit from that. I'd be happy if you mark it as 'correct' :)

Comment: @quqa123 when i add the timesince to the {{ like.like_date|timesince }}, i run into this error 'str' object has no attribute 'year', how do i resolve it ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calling the relational field like `user_name` in the template will output the models  `__str__` method so in case of a `User` it will be `username` as default which is connected to `email` here.
 To call any other field of the related model just call it like any other class attribute or method - `user_name.get_full_name` here

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to solve this problem with the help of the comment by @quqa123, I went into my view model and added get_full_name to username field in listview context_data username, like this (username.get_full_name) and then went into my template added the variable like this {{ username.get_full_name }} then it worked.